# redux reduce boilerplate for actions and reducer

Tags: javascript, redux

i try to figure out what the best practice for this situation.

2 context : SPORT todos & HOME todos.

so 2 action files:

```
export const SPORT_ADD_TODO = `[SPORT] ADD TODO`
export const HOME_ADD_TODO = `[HOME] ADD TODO`
```

and 2 reducer files

```
homeReducer(state, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
     case HOME_ADD_TODO:
        return Object.assing({}, state, {
           todos: action.payload
        })
     default:
        return state;
  }
}

sportReducer(state, action) {
      ....
}
```

have an official solution for this situation?
i don't want to repeat my self.
the reducer have the same functionality

Comment: When you say they have the `same functionality` - I have a hard time understanding what you're saying. Since there are 2 separate reducers, they are actually adding `todos` into 2 separate parts of the state tree. One on the `home` branch and one of the `sport` branch of the state. So are they actually doing the same thing, or are the method bodies just similar since you're performing "alike" actions?

Comment: yes they doing the same thing for other branch, but i dont want to copy past every time i have new branch. i try to understand what the solution for this problem without copy past action and reducers

Comment: Well each reducer only has access to its' own state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to think again on your app architecture. in general reusable reducer/actions is incorrect.

why it's incorrect? in present view, it seem's awesome to write reusable reducer and actions, less boilerplate, and not "DRY". in example of your app. 'ADD_TO_DO' for home and sport are equal.

but in future it will be dangerous, thinking your boss/costumers need future in sports add_to_do. if you change the logic in the reusable reducer. your app will broke. (you can start patch your reusable reducer with if statements to get it work but if your app grow it will be not flexible/ readable/ maintenance ).

so yes it seems you need to write 2 reducers in this case, and 2 actions files. in present it fill equal but in the future it will be advantage and flexible.

Answer (score 1):

In software development in general, when we want to create multiple instances of the similar objects, we use factories for object creation. Here the reducer in Redux context is just a pure function which is an object type is Javascript. So the factory rule applies here too.

Create a `createTodoReducer` factory:

```
function createTodoReducer(initialState, {addType}) {
  return function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
      case addType:
        return {...state, todos: action.payload}
    }
  }
}
```

Now use the factory to instantiate `sportTodosReducer` and `homeReducer`:

```
const homeReducer = createTodosReducer({todos: []}, {addType: 'HOME_ADD_TODO'});
const sportsReducer = createTodoReducer({todos: []}, {addType: 'SPORTS_ADD_TODO'})
```

You can add any types to modify reducer state such as addType and share the same logic by using the factory.

Comment: it's nice but the problem that i again need to rewrite all actions for any reducer! and for typescript is unfreindly

Comment: Since the logic of reducers is similar, means data types are similar too. So you can create factories for similar action creators too.

Answer (score 0):

Just found [Autodux](https://github.com/ericelliott/autodux).

Actions, reducer, initial state and selectors defined in one object.
If you just give an initial state it auto generates the rest upon the state shape.

Awesome!

```js
// From this
const actionTypes = {
  INCREMENT: 'INCREMENT',
  DECREMENT: 'DECREMENT'
}

const actions = {
  increment: () => ({type: actionTypes.INCREMENT}),
  decrement: () => ({type: actionTypes.DECREMENT})
}

const counter = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.INCREMENT:
      return state + 1
    case actionTypes.DECREMENT:
      return state - 1
    default:
      return state
  }
}

// To this
const counter = autodux({
  slice: 'counter',
  initial: 0,
  actions: {
    increment: state => state + 1,
    decrement: state => state - 1
  }
});
```